# Is there a way to catch same two exceptions for different logic in java?

Tags: java, spring, exception

I am writing a piece of program that connects to a database and does CRUD operations.
I have 5 methods: `getValues(), createValue(...), updateValue(...), getValue(...), deletevalue(...)`.
All of these methods throws the same 2 exceptions: `DatabaseInvalidRequestExcpetion` and `ServerExpection`.

The way I've implemented it now, all my methods have

```
try{ *some logic* }
catch(DatabaseInvalidRequestExcpetion ex1) {throw ex1}
catch(ServerExpection ex2) {throw ex2}
```

I don't want to repeat these try and catch blocks in all of my functions.

I've read about the Function fucntional interface in java 8, but my inputs are complex and can't be done with a lambda expression, because I check other stuff in the logic part.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `catch (DatabaseInvalidRequestExcpetion | ServerExcveption e) {throw e}`? what is your question here?

Comment: Noting also that you're likely doing too much in a single block.

Comment: I edited the question with "I  don't want to repeat these try and catch blocks in all of my functions."

Comment: Catching an exception and then in the catch block immediately throwing the same exception again is unnecessary. You can just as well remove the `try` and the catch blocks (and just have the content of the try-block).

Comment: I am also logging the exception in the catch blocks.

Comment: the tags mention Spring. Is this part of a web controller? Spring has built-in exception handling logic which you could use so you don't have to try/catch yourself all over the place.

Comment: if you do not want to repeat them, just use a delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using spring in your project so if you want to apply the same error handling logic for all your methods you can just propagate the exceptions and use one of the following options:

1. If you are using spring to create REST endpoints you can create an ExceptionHandler you can check the following documentation [exception handling](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)
2. If you are creating a different type of application with spring you can use spring aop with an After throwing advice so you can apply the same logic for different methods when the defined exceptions are thrown, you can check the following documentation [after-throwing-advice](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springaop/springaop_after_throwing1.htm)

I hope this is helpful for you, please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring AOP for achieving this. You can implement after throwing advice for all required methods (5 in your case) as Join Points. You can also use the same advice to handle any other exception types also being thrown from different part of your application if required.